# Which software programs can be used to study SRR (split ring resonator) based meta-material and its cloaking properties

Tags: software, metamaterials

I have been studying about [metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) and their amazing abilities to interact with EM Waves.
I came across a concept called Metamaterial cloaking (something like Harry Potter's invisible cloak kinda material). I also know that most of them are based on artificial structures called [Split Ring Resonators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-ring_resonator).
There have been some research works using [COMSOL](https://www.comsol.co.in/) for [metamaterial modelling](https://www.comsol.com/paper/comsol-multiphysics-in-plasmonics-and-metamaterials-12481) but I would like to know what are some better software programs that could be used to computationally study and research about metamaterials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not specialised in metamaterial modelling (even though my group does just that and I have designed a couple of SRRs myself), but I believe the most widely used software for designing antennas and metamaterials including SRRs is [CST Studio](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/products/cst-studio-suite/). It is equipped with many tools to design even complex nanostructures in a few clicks and run the full wave simulations.

CST can be integrated with matlab and controlled from a matlab code which is very useful to automate those structure designing and simulations. CST is meant for Windows OS but has a Linux distribution too which I managed to install and work with on my Ubuntu OS.

That being said, this is a commercial software, so you might have to look for a university/company license.